# O que é SPF e DKIM e porque precisamos de os configurar?

Tags: email, dkim

Sempre que falamos em emails, particularmente *newsletters*, surgem os termos *SPF* e *DKIM*.

Muitos serviços de *mailing* online pedem para configurar estes valores no alojamento web mas não referem os motivos, parecem assumir que já sabemos do que se trata.

## Pergunta

O que é o *SPF* e o *DKIM* e porque precisamos de os configurar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sender Policy Framework** ou **SPF** valida o dominio Vs. a resposta do servidor SMTP, de onde o email é originado.
Esta metodologia de forma a garantir que o email foi enviado efectivamente pelo servidor onde o dominio remetente, está configurado.

As configurações SPF, são realizadas e geridas pelo BIND (Berkeley Internet Name Daemon) ou outro serviço de DNS instalado, o qual gere os dominios e seus endereços.

**Exemplo de configuração SPF:**

> v=spf1 a mx o_meu_dominio.com ip4:9.110.8.1 ?all

Website Oficial SPF: http://www.openspf.org/

**DomainKeys Identified Mail** ou **DKIM** valida se o conteúdo do email durante o seu transporte, não foi alterado, no seu conteúdo ou headers.
Valida também se os anexos do email, caso existam, não foram alterados durante o transporte do servidor remetente até servidor destinatário.

No caso do DKIM, uma assinatura digital é incluida em todos os emails enviados do servidor emissor.

Este caso, à luz da segurança informática, é extremamente interessante devido à quantidade de intervenientes utilizados na verificação dos emails enviados, desde o MTA, OpenSSL, DNS.

**Exemplo de um DKIM:**

> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; d=o_meu_dominio.com; s=brisbane;
>        c=relaxed/simple; q=dns/txt; l=1234; t=1117574938; x=1118006938;
>        h=from:to:subject:date:keywords:keywords;
>        bh=MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTI=;
>        b=dzdVyOfAKCdLXdJOc9G2q8LoXSlEniSbav+yuU4zGeeruD00lszZ
>        VoG4ZHRNiYzR

Website Oficial DKIM: http://www.dkim.org/